# python: reading a string to int for comparison in for loop.

Tags: python, string

I'm new to this stuff so sorry if this is a dumb question. I've got this data which lists countries by GDP (from factbook). Here it is compiled into a single string:

> '\n1\tEuropean Union\t$   15,970,000,000,000\n2\tUnited States\t$
>   15,940,000,000,000\n3\tChina\t$   12,610,000,000,000\n4\tIndia\t$
>   4,761,000,000,000\n5\tJapan\t$    4,704,000,000,000\n6\tGermany\t$
>   3,250,000,000,000\n7\tRussia\t$    2,555,000,000,000\n8\tBrazil\t$
>   2,394,000,000,000\n9\tUnited Kingdom\t$
>   2,375,000,000,000\n10\tFrance\t$    2,291,000,000,000\n11\tItaly\t$
>   1,863,000,000,000\n12\tMexico\t$    1,788,000,000,000\n13\tKorea,
>   South\t$    1,640,000,000,000\n14\tCanada\t$
>   1,513,000,000,000\n15\tSpain\t$    1,434,000,000,000\n16\tIndonesia\t$
>   1,237,000,000,000\n17\tTurkey\t$    1,142,000,000,000\n18\tIran\t$
>   1,016,000,000,000\n19\tAustralia\t$     986,700,000,000\n20\tSaudi
>   Arabia\t$     921,700,000,000\n21\tTaiwan\t$
>   918,300,000,000\n22\tPoland\t$     814,100,000,000\n23\tArgentina\t$
>   755,300,000,000\n24\tNetherlands\t$
>   718,600,000,000\n25\tThailand\t$     662,600,000,000\n26\tSouth
>   Africa\t$     592,000,000,000\n27\tEgypt\t$
>   548,800,000,000\n28\tPakistan\t$     523,900,000,000\n29\tColombia\t$ 
>   511,100,000,000\n30\tMalaysia\t$     506,700,000,000\n31\tNigeria\t$
>   455,500,000,000\n32\tPhilippines\t$
>   431,300,000,000\n33\tBelgium\t$     427,200,000,000\n34\tVenezuela\t$ 
>   408,500,000,000\n35\tSweden\t$     399,400,000,000\n36\tHong Kong\t$
>   375,500,000,000\n37\tSwitzerland\t$
>   369,400,000,000\n38\tAustria\t$     364,900,000,000\n39\tUkraine\t$
>   340,700,000,000\n'

my script goes through this and I want to it compare `x+1` in the for loop the the integer after `n` each time it hits an `n` if there's that number after `n`. I ask it to check if it's the same as the counter, if so, I print `"here's a line"`. Here's my script:

```
DataCounter = 1
for x in data:
    if x == "n":
        if x+1 == DataCounter:
            print("new line")
            print(DataCounter)
            DataCounter = DataCounter + 1
```

I know it's not perfect and I know my example only goes up to 9 but it'll do the job for me (could have ambiguities). I'm having trouble since it compares DataCounter, which is an int to `x+1` which is a string. What do I do? Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 3, in <module>
    if x+1 == DataCounter:
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: I'm sorry that the formatting sucks here. I might just redo this question.

Comment: `\n` is not a slash followed by an `n`. It is a single character, a newline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and please don't repeat your question! I have suggested an edit, which will appear shortly, but for the future: to highlight short parts of code surround with backtick characters (`), and to format longer blocks highlight and press ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\t` and `\n` are single characters, for tab and newline respectively. You can't treat them as two characters.

You can turn the whole thing into a list of (index, country, GDP) 3-tuples in one go as follows:

```
data2 = [(int(a), b, int(c.strip('$').replace(',', ''))) 
         for a, b, c in [s.split("\t") 
         for s in data.strip("\n").split("\n")]]
```

It is then much easier to loop through the list and test whichever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import decimal

def money(s, reg=re.compile('[^0-9\.+-]+')):
    return decimal.Decimal(reg.sub('', s))

data = data.strip().split('\n')                             # break the text into a string per country
data = [row.split('\t') for row in data]                    # break each country into three strings
data = [[int(n), name, money(val)] for n,name,val in data]    # convert data types appropriately
```

Data now looks like

```
[
    [1, 'European Union', Decimal('15970000000000')],
    [2, 'United States', Decimal('15940000000000')],
    [3, 'China', Decimal('12610000000000')],
    [4, 'India', Decimal('4761000000000')],
    [5, 'Japan', Decimal('4704000000000')],
    # ...
    [38, 'Austria', Decimal('364900000000')],
    [39, 'Ukraine', Decimal('340700000000')]
]
```